# Installing sdk using python, “SyntaxError: invalid syntax”

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

The Razer Hydra SDK requires to lanch install.py in order to install the sdk

I installed [this](https://www.python.org/download/windows/), then I opened the IDLE, loaded the install.py inside the SDK, pressed F5 and I get

“SyntaxError: invalid syntax”

here at the second ", the one closing the first print

```
print "\nSixense SDK Installation Script v%02d.%02d.%02d" % ( self.versionMajor, self.versionMinor, self.versionMacro )
      if( not cmdOpts.printVersionAndExit ):
         print "============================================"
```

I dont know python, I wonder how such a company may deliver crap sdk, but this is it

If you want the full code, [here](http://pastebin.com/VbVsGbHr)

Comment: The code is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: The SDK still looks like crap though.

Comment: @vaultah you saw? :D